# How can I run ajax call from within error function from another ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run an ajax call. If there is an error returned, I would like to capture the responseText and send that to another ajax call which has a php script that will mail the error to me.

```
      $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/add_remove_favorite.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "listingType" : listingType,
                "listingId" : listingId
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('The first ajax call worked');
            }, //end first ajax success
            error: function(data){ //If the listing doesn't update, display an error message
                var currentURL = window.location;       

                $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/error_email.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        "url" : currentURL,
                        "errorMessage" : data.responseText
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('The email sent successfully');
                    },

                    error: function(data){ //If the listing doesn't update, display an error message
                        alert('The email did not send');
                    }
                }); //end second ajax call

            } //end first ajax error
        }); //end first ajax call
```

I am able to get the error from the first ajax call, so I know that one works good. But for some reason, the mail script on the second ajax call won't send, and it won't return the success or error message, which tells me the ajax call is not working.

How can I run ajax call from within error function from another ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `window.location.href`. `window.location` is an object.

Comment: Yeah! That fixed the problem. I dont' understand why I didn't get a error response if it was the wrong type, but im glad it works now. Thanks for your help!